# How to upload files to Google Drive from React Using Uppy or Uppload library

Tags: upload, uppy

I'm a beginner with JavaScript React and learning about file transfer handling. My question is after have read about [Uppy](https://uppy.io/) and [Uppload](https://github.com/elninotech/uppload) that both simplifies upload of files but non of them can Upload to Google Drive.

I have tried to understand how this limitation works and solutions maybe. I read something about that Google Drive can't receive XHR Upload directly, is this the reason why this library's can't work with Google Drive?

Is it possible to use the [Uppy](https://uppy.io/) and [Uppload](https://github.com/elninotech/uppload) to let User select files but then I could create my own Google Drive Uploader and by so no use Uppy and Uppload internal uploader?